# Insert into Select query returns duplicate rows

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

```
INSERT INTO INT_TBL_2 (product_id, UR_id, lang_code, country_code, named_obj_class,     
                       named_obj_phonemes, total_phonemes, total_named_objects)
SELECT product_id, UR_id, lang_code, country_code, named_obj_class, 
       SUM(named_obj_phonemes), SUM(total_phonemes), SUM(total_named_objects) 
FROM INT_TBL_1 
WHERE named_obj_class = "city" 
GROUP BY product_id, UR_id, lang_code, country_code, named_obj_class
```

My query yields correct result where run manually on Oracle developer. But the same query, when called via C++ code, yields the results duplicated 5000 times.

Note that the table `INT_TBL_2` is always empty (newly created) before insertion.

Comment: What is your C++ code? Are you executing the statement multiple times there?

Comment: Yes, there shouldn't be any difference between execute the code in oracle or using C++

Comment: Please edit your post with the C++ code.  Also, indicate which driver you are using.

Comment: No the query is placed inside a function that is being called only once. I put print statements to check if it was being called multiple times by any chance but the output indicated that it was called only one time.

Comment: I do not have the c++ code at the moment. I will share the code as soon as I can.

Comment: "the function" may be called only once, but if the function itself has the INSERT statement within a loop, it will still execute the statement multiple times.

Comment: I found the cause for it. I was using a otl_nocommit_stream from the otl library for insertion and the stream buffer size was set to 5000 instead of 1. Hence the records were duplicated 5000 times.